# malloc'd pointer inside struct that is passed by value

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-value

I am putting together a project in C where I must pass around a variable length byte sequence, but I'm trying to limit malloc calls due to potentially limited heap.

Say I have a struct, `my_struct`, that contains the variable length byte sequence, `ptr`, and a function, `my_func`, that creates an instance of `my_struct`. In `my_func`, `my_struct.ptr` is malloc'd and `my_struct` is returned by value. `my_struct` will then be used by other functions being passed by value: `another_func`. Code below.

1. Is this "safe" to do against memory leaks provided somewhere on the original or any copy of `my_struct` when passed by value, I call `my_struct_destroy` or free the malloc'd pointer? Specifically, is there any way that when `another_func` returns, that `inst.ptr` is open to being rewritten or dangling?
2. Since stackoverflow doesn't like opinion-based questions, are there any good references that discuss this behavior? I'm not sure what to search for.

```
typedef struct {
    char * ptr;
} my_struct;

// allocates n bytes to pointer in structure and initializes.
my_struct my_func(size_t n) {
    my_struct out = {(char *) malloc(n)};
    /* initialization  of out.ptr */

    return out;
}

void another_func(my_struct inst) {
    /* 
    do something using the passed-by-value inst 
    are there problems with inst.ptr here or after this function returns?
    */
}

void my_struct_destroy(my_struct * ms_ptr) {
    free(ms_ptr->ptr);
    ms_ptr->ptr = NULL;
}

int main() {
    my_struct inst = my_func(20);
    
    another_func(inst);
    
    my_struct_destroy(&inst);
}
```

Comment: As long as your "my_struct_destroy or free" is after all uses of that buffer, you do not write code that overwrites the pointer itself with some other (address) value, and you do not attempt "my_struct_destroy or free" more than once then it should be fine. The issue would be if you mess up any of the conditions, possibly without noticing, possibly at a latter time during code maintenance.

Comment: Returning `my_struct` by value instead of by pointer does buck a lot of C conventions.

Comment: Why are your heap "potentially limited"? Systems with limited heap are usually microcontroller systems where you shouldn't be using the heap at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I's safe to pass and return a struct containing a pointer by value as you did it. It contains a copy of `ptr`. Nothing is changed in the calling function.  There would, of course, be a big problem if `another_func` frees `ptr` and then the caller tries to use it or free it again.
2. Locality of alloc+free is a best practice. Wherever possible, make the function that allocates an object also responsible for freeing it. Where that's not feasible, malloc and free of the same object should be in the same source file. Where that's not possible (think complex graph data structure with deletes), the collection of files that manage objects of a given type should be clearly identified and conventions documented. There's a common technique useful for programs (like compilers) that work in stages where much of the memory allocated in one stage should be freed before the next starts. Here, memory is only `malloc`ed in big blocks by a manager. From these, the manager allocs objects of any size. But it knows only one way to free: all at once, presumably at the end of a stage. This is a `gcc` idea: obstacks. When allocation is more complex, bigger systems implement some kind of garbage collector. Beyond these ideas, there are as many ways to manage C storage as there are colors. Sorry I don't have any pointers to references (pun intended :)

If you only have one variable-length field and its size doesn't need to be dynamically updated, consider making the last field in the struct an array to hold it. This is okay with the C standard:

```
typedef struct {
    ... other fields
    char a[1]; // variable length
} my_struct;

my_struct my_func(size_t n) {
  my_struct *p = malloc(sizeof *p + (n - 1) * sizeof p->a[0]);
  ... initialize fields of p
  return p;
}
```

This avoids the need to separately free the variable length field. Unfortunately it only works for one.

If you're okay with gcc extensions, you can allocate the array with size zero. In C 99, you can get the same effect with `a[]`. This avoids the `- 1` in the size calculation.

Comment: Note that as of C99, `char a[];` is standardaized  as the form for a flexible array member. It is no longer an extension and `char a[1];` is now non-standard. [See here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/154089) And, if you want [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL38-C.+Use+the+correct+syntax+when+declaring+a+flexible+array+member).

Comment: UV from an old-timer for showing techniques used in **reams** of production code written before the authors of new standards were born. Most companies are not willing to pay for days/weeks of 'revising' code to conform to new standards. In fact, many companies will only allow **minimal revision** (under duress) when business requires alterations to production code.

Comment: @Gene, Corner case: With VLA `char a[];`, code nicely handles `my_func(0)`.  With this answer's `(n - 1) * sizeof p->a[0]` we have trouble.

Comment: @Fe2O3 " Most companies are not willing to pay for days/weeks of 'revising' code to conform to new standards"  No but they probably have to pay for bug fixes. _This was always a bug_ - getting rid of the old "struct hack" as seen here wasn't just some cosmetic thing, it caused real and often subtle bugs. I was dealing with bugs caused by it as late as the 2000s (many years after C99 was released), when writing code dealing with bitmaps and bitmap headers. Porting seemingly working code from one compiler to another, for the same target, caused file generation to become corrupt.

Comment: @Lundin Fair enough. "porting code"... Yes, when the substructure changes, cracks will appear. I once worked for an institution keeping an OS and DBS on life-support because the feared "re-write" was too terrifying to consider. How many Win-XP boxes are still out there?? (How many MS-DOS boxes??? *shiver*)

Comment: A lot of good information in the answer and comments, thanks!